# Remove bad VBA code from Visio file after it is selected but before it is opened

Tags: c#, vba, visio, add-on

I have a set of Visio drawing files that contain VBA code that is no longer needed (in fact, errors occur when trying to open a file as the module referenced in the VBA no longer exists).

Due to the nature of the add-on I'm working on, my users must keep Macros and VBA enabled.  However, any file they open in Visio needs to have its VBA code automatically removed first.

I can hit a breakpoint in my code when the Visio application is launched, but before a file is selected to Open.  I can also hit a breakpoint in my code after the file is selected and loaded in Visio.  I cannot seem to find a way to get a break after the file is selected, but before Visio loads it.

Looking at the Visio Interop assemblies in C#, I can see Visio.Application events called "OnDocumentOpened" and "OnDocumentCreated", but they aren't triggered until 'after' the file has been loaded.  I couldn't find anything called "BeforeDocumentOpened" or "BeforeDocumentCreated" unfortunately, which is basically exactly what I need.  There are other events with similar names like "BeforeDocumentSave" and "BeforeDocumentClose", but obviously they are not what I'm looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Question: Are there any methods to capture when Visio attempts to open a drawing file but before it's actually opened?  This is where I intend to remove the VBA code from the file, which I've already implemented.  If not, any known workarounds to achieving something similar?

Example of the bad VBA I want to remove:

```
Private Sub Document_DocumentCreated(ByVal doc As Visio.Document)
    Call Initialize(doc)
End Sub

Private Sub Document_DocumentOpened(ByVal doc As Visio.Document)
    Call Initialize(doc)
End Sub

Private Sub Initialize(doc As Visio.Document)
    Dim myLib As Object
    Set myLib = CreateObject("MODULE_NAME") 'Errors here, since we got rid of the module
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Based on your code you are writing this in VBA as a macro right? Or are you writing this in C# and C# is making use of the VBA code via macros? ... If the later, can you disable macros for them, open the file, re-enable macros?

Comment: The code that listens in on the Visio events is written in C# yes (the add-on I'm working on is partly C#, partly Visual Basic - and the back-end stuff is in Fortran).  I will try your suggestion out tomorrow and provide an update!

Comment: FYI - looks like your macro tag got pulled. I suspect that even though this is strongly involving macros, this isn't doable through macros. I assume that because I'm pretty sure that @braX has forgotten more than I know about macros ... or not forgotten anything and the gulf is even wider.

Comment: Here is the description for the [macro] tag: ***DO NOT USE for VBA / MS-Office languages. Use the respective [vba] tags instead.***

Comment: ....my users must keep Macros and VBA enabled....Visio needs to have its VBA code automatically removed first >>> This is sure confusing. Do you want VBA or you don't?

Comment: In a previous release of the add-in I inherited to work on, VBA code was automatically injected into the models users opened.  That same VBA code now fails upon opening the file, but the users still need the ability to create and maintain their own macros and other custom VBA (I've already written a routine in C# to remove this very specific code, I just cant find a way to trigger it "before" Visio takes control and opens the file, yielding the error.  I just need to remove this erroneous code "after" the user selects the file to open, but before Visio takes control.

Comment: @Roger 's suggestion is a good approach, but unfortunately won't work for my case.  Ex., on startup, I can disable macros and wait for user to open a file.  User opens file, I remove the bad VBA, then re-enable macros.  What if within the same session, user opens another file?  I hit the same roadblock where I need to listen on an event that happens after a user selects the path to the file, but before Visio actually opens it.  It's frustrating haha

Comment: This was my first question posted, so apologies for the 'macro' tag confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not overdo it. You can upgrade your users. Like, provide a script (or some sort of functionality in the installer, or some button in the application) to update the diagrams. I.e. a separate function, just don't do it on opening the diagram. Since it is one-time operation, the users probably won't cry about that. And you won't add "garbage" one-time code to the application...

Just to be clear: the event you are looking for "before document opened" does not exist.

Comment: What I will do is implement a popup on startup (with a tickbox to 'not show again') warning users to convert their old files, with my own file browse dialog to allow them to select one or more files to 'scrub'.  I'll also include this button/feature in the add-on ribbon, so that users who ticked 'dont show again' can still access the feature later.  

Accepting this answer since it helped me come up with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

One other tip regarding VBA macros in Visio: put the code in a stencil. When you have code in drawings, it gets proliferated in *every* drawing that is created. If you need to change the code, then you have to find all of the drawings and change all of the code.

Instead, you can put macros in a stencil. The stencil can be put in the user's Favorites folder, so the stencil will be easily accessible from any drawing (Shapes > More Shapes > My Shapes > Favorites, usually in the panel docked on the left).

The stencil doesn't have to contain any master shapes, it can just serve as a "code library" that users can load for any drawing. But it is a separate file. If you need to update the macros, you can then distribute a new stencil and have users overwrite the old one.

Now all of your *drawing files* will be free of code, and you won't have to update potentially thousands of VBA projects every time a change is required.